# Examples of very concise Forth applications?

Tags: forth

In [this talk](http://www.ultratechnology.com/1xforth.htm), Chuck Moore (the creator of Forth) makes some very bold, sweeping claims, such as:

1. "Every application that I have seen that I didn't code has ten times as much code in it as it needs"
2. "About a thousand instructions seems about right to me to do about anything"
3. "If you are writing code that needs [local variables] you are writing non-optimal code. Don't use local variables."

I'm trying to figure out whether Mr. Moore is a) an absolutely brilliant genius or b) a crackpot. But that's a subjective question, and  I'm not looking for the answer to that question here. What I am looking for are examples of complex, real-world problems which can be solved in "1000 instructions or less" using Forth, and source code demonstrating how to do so. An example showing just one non-trivial piece of a real-world system would be fine, but no "toy" code samples which could be duplicated in 5 or 10 lines of another high-level language, please.

If you have written real-world systems in Forth, using just a small amount of source code, but aren't at liberty to show the source (because it is proprietary), I'd still like to hear about it.

Comment: I've seen a number of closed question where it is argued that it sollicits debates where in fact the question asks about real world examples or experiences. What is subjective, debatable or discussion provoking if I present a full Pentium II assembler in 90 lines?

Comment: @AlbertvanderHorst Absolutely. This is the worst thing about SO.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to understand that [Chuck Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_H._Moore) is a little different than you and me. He was trained in an era when mainframe computers consisted of 16 KB or its equivalent in core memory, and he was able to do quite a lot of things with the computers of the time. Perhaps the biggest success for Forth, outside of his OKAD-II chip design package (that's not a typo), was a multi-user multi-tasking Forth system responsible for concurrently controlling data acquisition instruments and data analysis/visualization software at [NRAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Radio_Astronomy_Observatory) on a fairly modestly sized computer barely able to compile [Fortran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran) source code on its own.

What he calls an "application", we might consider to be a "component" of a larger, more nebulous thing called an application. More generally, it's good to keep in mind that one Moore "application" is more or less equivalent to one "view" in an [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) triad today. To keep memory consumption small, he relies heavily on overlays and just-in-time compilation techniques. When switching from one program interface to another, it typically involves recompiling the entire application/view from source. This happens so fast you don't know it's happening. Kind of like how Android recompiles [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) code to native [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) code when you activate an application every time today.

At any given time, OKAD-II has no more than about 2.5 KB of its code loaded into memory and running. However, the on-disk source for OKAD-II is considerably larger than 2.5 KB.  Though, it is still significantly more compact than its nearest competitor, [SPICE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE).

I'm often curious about Chuck Moore's views and find his never-ending strive for simplicity fascinating. So, in [MythBusters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters) fashion, I put his claims to the test by trying to design my own system as minimally as I could make it. I'm happy to report he's very nearly spot-on in his claims, on both hardware and software issues. Case in point, during last September's  [Silicon Valley Forth Interest Group](http://www.forth.org/svfig/) (SVFIG) meeting, I used my Kestrel-2 itself to generate video for the slide deck. This required I wrote a slide presentation program for it, which took up 4 KB of memory for the code, and 4 KB for the slide deck data structures. With an average space of six bytes per Forth word (for reasons I won't go into here), the estimate of "about 1000 (Forth) instructions" for the application is just about spot on to what Chuck Moore estimates his own "applications" to be.

If you're interested in speaking to real-world Forth coders (or who have done so in the past, as it increasingly seems to be), and you happen to be in the [Bay Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_Bay_Area), the Silicon Valley Forth Interest Group still meets every fourth Saturday of the month, except for November and December, which is the third Saturday. If you're interested in attending a meeting, even if only to interview Forth coders and get a taste of what "real-world" Forth is like, check us out on meetup.com and tag along. We also new stream our meetings on YouTube, but we're not very good at it. We're abusing inappropriate hardware and software to do our bidding, since we have a budget of zero for this sort of thing.  :)

Answer (score 28):

Forth is indeed amazingly compact! Words without formal parameters (and zero-operand instructions at the hardware - e.g. the [GA144](http://www.greenarraychips.com/)) saves a lot. The other main contributor to its compactness is the absolutely relentless factoring of redundant code that the calling convention and concatenative nature affords.

I don't know if it qualifies as a non-toy example, but the [Turtle Graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics) implementation for the [Fignition](https://sites.google.com/site/libby8dev/fignition) (in FigForth) is just **307 bytes** compiled and fits in a single source block! This includes the fixed point trig and all the normal turtle commands. This isn't the best example of readable Forth because of trying to squeeze it into a single source block with single-character names and such:

```
\ 8.8 fixed point sine table lookup
-2 var n F9F2 , E9DD , CEBD , AA95 , 7F67 , 4E34 , 1A c,
: s abs 3C mod dup 1D > if 3C swap - then dup E > if
  -1 1E rot - else 1 swap then n + c@ 1+ * ;

0 var x 0 var y 0 var a
0 var q 0 var w 
: c 9380 C80 0 fill ; \ clear screen
: k >r 50 + 8 << r> ! ;
: m dup q @ * x +! w @ * y +! ; \ move n-pixels (without drawing)
: g y k x k ; \ go to x,y coord
: h dup a ! dup s w ! 2D + s q ! ; \ heading
: f >r q @ x @ y @ w @ r 0 do >r r + >r over + \ forward n-pixels
  dup 8 >> r 8 >> plot r> r> loop o y ! x ! o r> o ;
: e key 0 vmode cls ; \ end
: b 1 vmode 1 pen c 0 0 g 0 h ; \ begin
: t a @ + h ; \ turn n-degrees
```

Using it is extremely concise as well.

```
: sin 160 0 do i i s 4 / 80 + plot loop ;
```

[image: Sine]

```
: burst 60 0 do 0 0 g i h 110 f loop ;
```

[image: Burst]

```
: squiral -50 50 g 20 0 do 100 f 21 t loop ;
```

[image: Squiral]

```
: circle 60 0 do 4 f 1 t loop ; 
: spiral 15 0 do circle 4 t loop ;
```

[image: Spiral]

```
: star 5 0 do 80 f 24 t loop ; 
: stars 3 0 do star 20 t loop ;
```

[image: Stars]

```
: rose 0 50 0 do 2 + dup f 14 t loop ;
```

[image: Rose]

```
: hp 15 0 do 5 f 1 t loop 15 0 do 2 f -1 t loop ; 
: petal hp 30 t hp 30 t ; 
: flower 15 0 do petal 4 t loop ;
```

[image: Flower]

(shameless blog plug: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashleyf/archive/2012/02/18/turtle-graphics-on-the-fignition.aspx)

Comment: For a real taste of crazy-concise Forth code, take a look at Chuck Moore's own code! Download the GreenArrays tools (http://www.greenarraychips.com/home/support/download-02a.html) and look browse the source blocks (either in their editor, or in the EVB001-02a.html file).

Answer (score 14):

What is not well understood today is the way Forth anticipated an approach to coding that became popular early in the 21st century in association with [agile methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development). Specifically:

- Forth introduced the notion of tiny method coding -- the use of small objects with small methods. You could make a case for [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) and [Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29) here too, but in the late 1980s both Smalltalk and Lisp practice tended toward larger and more complex methods. Forth always embraced very small methods, if only because it encouraged doing so much on the stack.
- Forth, even more than Lisp, popularized the notion that the interpreter was just a little software pattern, not a dissertation-sized brick. Got a problem that's hard to code? The Forth solution *had* to be, "write a little language", because that's what Forth programming was.

Forth was very much a product of memory and time constraints, of an era where computers were incredibly tiny and terribly slow. It was a beautiful design that lets you build an operating system and a compiler in a matchbox.

Answer (score 7):

An example of just how compact Forth can be, is Samuel Falvo's screencast  *[Over the Shoulder 1 - Text Preprocessing in Forth](http://www.falvotech.com/content/videos/ots-01.mpg)* (1h 06 min 25 secs, 101 MB, MPEG-1 format - at least [VLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player) can play it). [Alternative source](http://forthworks.com/) ("Links and Resources" -> "Videos").

Comment: I have re-used some of the code in that video in a later project, wherein I wrote a blog engine in (32-bit only) Forth.  The resulting code is actually even more compact, as I was able to re-use some other aspects of the blog.  The macro expander is found here:

https://bitbucket.org/kc5tja/unsuitable/src/8739e927fee7/share/unsuitable/response.fs?at=default

Typical use is here:

https://bitbucket.org/kc5tja/unsuitable/src/8739e927fee7102757d9ceffdb57899367481d4b/share/unsuitable/m-rss.fs?at=default

Answer (score 7):

Forth Inc's polyFORTH/32 VAX/VMS assembler definitions took some 8 blocks of source.  A VAX assembler, in 8K of source.  Commented.  I'm still amazed, 30 years later.

I can't verify at the moment, but I'm guessing the instruction count to parse those CODE definitions would be in the low hundreds.  And when I said 'took some 8 blocks', it still takes, the application using that nucleus is live and in production, 30 years later.

Comment: If you want to see an equally compact assembler for the more familiar Pentium_I (including 16 bits code, floating point, sib byte, addressing modes, prefixes) check out the built in assembler for ciforth. It is a compact version of the well documented ciasdis. Intel is barocque and irregular, still this is limited to 15 screens.http://home.hccnet.nl/a.w.m.van.der.horst/ciforth.html

Comment: @AlbertvanderHorst Nice.  And by nice, I mean awesome.  With LOCATE no less.  And with the ci86.lina64.s file (which built lina, clean, first try by the way) I know where my reading time is going to be spent this evening.  Well done, Albert.  Thanks for the heads up.